# VB.net Random form load

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone know if there exist some kind of code to load a random form. Like if button1 is clicked then either form 2 form 3 or form 4 will open. Does some kind of code exist to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only working with a few forms a simple select block would work well here:

```
    Dim rnd As New Random(Date.Now.Millisecond)
    Dim newform As New Form
    Select Case rnd.Next(0, 3)
        Case 0
            newform = New Form2
        Case 1
            newform = New Form3
        Case 2
            newform = New Form4
    End Select
    newform.Show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number between 2 and 4 and then load the form by that name; this assumes your forms are named `Form2`, `Form3` and `Form4`:

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(1, 4)
```

To create the actual `Form` object, you will need the fully qualified name of the object (`YourNamespace.Form2` for example), like this:

```
Dim myRandomFormType As Type = Type.GetType("YourNamespace.Form" & RandomNumber.ToString())
Dim myRandomFormObject As Object
myRandomFormObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myRandomFormType)
```

Finally, you need to cast the object to the base class `Form` so we can show it, like this:

```
Dim myRandomForm As Form = CType(myRandomFormObject, Form)
myRandomForm.Show()
```

Comment: Your idea was great! But a little to complicated for the purpose. But thanks any way!